# For loop creates error when recursivley permutating strings in C

Tags: c, recursion, permutation

I am new to C and am trying to write a function that returns the all the permutations of a subset of size k of a string using recursion.  For example, for the string 'abc' and k = 1, I would get 'a', 'b' and 'c', for k = 2 I would get 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb' and 'cc', and so on.

I want to return all the generated strings so that I can do other things with them - right now it just prints them out, but I will use them later.  I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CHARS "abc"

char *recur(char* prefix, int k, int n);

int main(void)
{     
    int k = 2; //for example
    int n = strlen(CHARS); //set n as length of CHARS
    //print string generated by recur
    printf("string: %s\n", recur("", k, n));
}

char *recur(char *prefix, int k, int n)
{
    //if base case (have already added all letters), return string
    if (k == 0)
    {
        return prefix;
    }
    //otherwise, add character from CHARS to string
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            // for each letter in CHARS, make a new prefix and add a letter from chars to it
            int prefLen = strlen(prefix);
            char newPrefix[prefLen + 2];
            strcpy(newPrefix, prefix);
            newPrefix[prefLen] = CHARS[i];
            newPrefix[prefLen + 1] = '\0';
            return recur(newPrefix, k-1, n);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the error 'recur1.c:40:1: error: control may reach end of non-void function
      [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]' when trying to compile.

To explore this a bit further, I removed the for loop which results in a reversed string:

```
char *recur(char *prefix, int k, int n)
{
    //if base case (have already added all letters), return string
    if (k == 0)
    {
        return prefix;
    }
    //otherwise, add character from CHARS to string
    else
    {
        //make a new array called newPrefix, copy current prefix into it and add new letter from CHARS
        int prefLen = strlen(prefix);
        char newPrefix[prefLen + 2];
        strcpy(newPrefix, prefix);
        newPrefix[prefLen] = CHARS[k-1];
        newPrefix[prefLen + 1] = '\0';
        return recur(newPrefix, k-1, n);
    }
}
```

After substitution of this second function, the code compiles without any issues.  Any ideas as to why the version with a for loop won't compile?

Comment: what if `n <= 0` ?

Comment: `char newPrefix[prefLen + 2];` is a llocal variable. It is __lost__ when the function returns.

Comment: As a side note, there is no need for the `else` since you return from the body of the `if`.

Comment: What's the point of a loop, if you already return in the first iteration?

Answer (score 1):

If `n <= 0`, then the `for` loop will never be entered, and so the `return` statement in the loop body will never be reached. Since there's no `return` statement after the loop, the compiler complains (rightly so).

That said : are you sure it's not a mistake to have an unconditional `return`  statement inside the loop body ? That makes the loop quite useless.

Answer (score 0):

If `i < n` is `0` when `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` is encountered then program control does not enter the `for` loop body, and a `return` statement is not reached. Should the `return` statement really be in the `for` loop body?

If that happens, the behaviour of the whole program is *undefined*. Your compiler is warning you of that, and you have elevated warnings to fail program compilation.

Worse than that, `newPrefix` has *automatic storage duration*. You are returning a pointer to it, and that pointer is invalid in the function caller. That's more *undefined behaviour*.